# How to get the NSData from a file path in KMM?

Tags: swift, nsdata, kotlin-multiplatform

Currently, I am building the app in KMM, which has a feature to capture images.
Once the image is captured got the URL of the file, and then I am saving the path in SqlDelight DB.

I tried to save both paths, i.e URL.path as well as URL.absoluteString.

Now to sync the stored path to the server I need to get the byte Array of these images, to get the byte Array, First I need to get the NSData from the path.

But it's always returning as null. My current actuals for iOS inside common code is -

```
NSData.create(contentsOfFile = filePath) -- > null

NSFileManager().contentsAtPath(filePath) -- > null
```

The above method is always returning null for the NSData,
but when I am accessing the same URL.path inside the swift module, it is able to get the NSData object.

```
let data = NSData(contentsOfFile: imagePath) -> getting the NSData
```

Please help me to get the NSData object inside the common code, or any other alternative, except I don't want to store the byte array in DB.

Comment: Don't use `NSData/NSFileManager` in Swift at all. There are `Data` and `FileManager`. And prefer always the URL based API over the path based. Basically file system URLs are created from the `path` with `URL(fileURLWithPath:)` and remote URLs from `absoluteString` with `URL(string:)`

Comment: @vadian In kotlin multiplatform, swift can't be used in common code. 
Anyways thanks for sharing the info.

Comment: Could you share more code? And version of KMM and XCode? Are you sure that you are correctly send `path` to common code?  `NSData.create(contentsOfFile = filePath)` should work fine with `URL.path` / `URL.relativePath`. Don't use `URL.absoluteString` it is returning URL string representation, not path.